# Error while executing "paster shell example.ini" in reddit.com

Tags: python, web-applications, pylons, reddit

Friends!!! I am frustated since last five days working on implementing
reddit.com on a ubuntu 9.10 machine.

Yes, I know that reddit.com has been tested on ubuntu intrepid.  But
now i want to install it on U9.10

I have installed postgresql database, created user copied the files,
and installed all the dependencies.

Everything is installed perfectly as described in the document
http://code.reddit.com/wiki/RedditStartToFinishIntrepid
until the line:

> $ paster shell example.ini

this line gives me a error and i couldnt figure out where the problem
lies.

```
Error:
/home/ubuntu/reddit/r2/r2/lib/utils/utils.py:29: DeprecationWarning:
the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  import re, datetime, math, random, string, sha, os
/home/ubuntu/reddit/r2/r2/lib/contrib/memcache.py:50:
DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  from md5 import md5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/paster", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.3', 'console_scripts', 'paster')
()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 84, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 123, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 218, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-
py2.6.egg/pylons/commands.py", line 341, in command
    conf = appconfig(config_name, relative_to=here_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 215, in appconfig
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 248, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 278, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 409, in get_context
    section)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 431, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 361, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 248, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 285, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 561, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.3.3-
py2.6.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 587, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1913,
in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(),
['__name__'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/reddit/r2/r2/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from r2.config.middleware import make_app
  File "/home/ubuntu/reddit/r2/r2/config/middleware.py", line 30, in
<module>
    from pylons.error import error_template
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-
py2.6.egg/pylons/error.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pylons.middleware import media_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pylons-0.9.6.2-
py2.6.egg/pylons/middleware.py", line 11, in <module>
    from webhelpers.rails.asset_tag import javascript_path
**ImportError: No module named rails.asset_tag**
```

Kindly guys please help me, take me out of my own frustration.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Newer version of python-webhelpers doesn't have asset_tag.py, you need to install an older version (0.6.4) for Pylons 0.9.6:

wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/W/WebHelpers/WebHelpers-0.6.4.tar.gz && tar -xf WebHelpers-0.6.4.tar.gz && cd WebHelpers-0.6.4 && python setup.py build && sudo python setup.py install && cd .. && sudo rm -r WebHelpers-0.6.4*

Comment: See this discussion for more info: http://groups.google.com/group/reddit-dev/browse_thread/thread/15ccb9346cdbf0a0/344fd022ce271d7a?#344fd022ce271d7a